# c++ syntax to find min in a list

Tags: c++, list, syntax, min

I see some complicated discussion on this topic but I'm failing to make what should be a very simple piece of code work.  I've found two ways to make it work but I'm puzzled by the some issues of syntax.  I just want to find the minimum value in a list.  This works:

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int main(void)
{
  auto init_list = {10, 20, 30};
  list<int> alist(init_list);

  list<int>::iterator minnum = min_element(begin(alist), end(alist));

  cout << "The min in the list is: " << *minnum << endl;
  return(1);
}
```

But there is also the definition of min() which takes an initializer_list as an argument.  I think I am misunderstanding the syntax of it.  Since I've already defined an init_list I can call

```
int minint = min(init_list);
```

and that works.  But I don't understand why.  The documentation on min says this call should be of form:

```
template< class T, class Compare >
T min( std::initializer_list<T> ilist, Compare comp );
```

So shouldn't I have to specify a < comparison operator to be able to use this (apparently not...why?)?  However, I don't know how to pass this operator correctly, and have been unable to come up with a clear explanation.  Each of the following generate a wide variety of syntax errors:

```
int minint = min(init_list, operator<);
int minint = min(init_list, int::operator<);
```

How am I supposed to pass the operator?  Clearly it doesn't matter in this case but if my list was not a list of ints but a list of some custom type with overloaded operators then would I need to pass an operator< ?  Or does the syntax simply mean that class T must have a comparison operator defined, but you never have to specify it in the min function call?

Comment: Where did you find this documentation?

Comment: I found it at [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/).  But as Tomasz Klak correctly points out below I must not have been reading carefully enough since I missed one of the function definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [version of min](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) (third declaration) which takes only initialization list.

And if you want to be explicit about comparing with `<` relation, use [std::less](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less):

```
int minint = min(init_list, std::less<int>());
```

Comment: Thanks, clearly I wasn't reading that definition carefully enough.  And now I've answered my other question.  I'll post my answer below as soon as I accept your answer.  Sorry I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote your answer, but I see other people are doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tomasz Klak.  I'm pretty new to operator overloading so I didn't know the std::less syntax.  That's very useful to know.  Clearly I wasn't reading carefully enough, since I missed that other definition of min().  My other question was about how this works with custom objects.  I think I've answered that for myself now.  Here's what I've found.

You can make an initialization list of custom objects.  For example, I have a very simple class that I call Double_list_struct, which is just a container for an int (the index) and a double (the value), with some typical member functions (constructors, getters, setters, toString() and overloaded operators, including operator<).  So I can make an initialization list of it by:

```
Double_list_struct doub1(1,5.5);
Double_list_struct doub2(1,3.5);
Double_list_struct doub3(1,26.5);

auto init_list_doub = {doub1, doub2, doub3};
```

Having done this the min() function works on it perfectly well.

```
Double_list_struct mindoub = min(init_list_doub);
```

I assume (but haven't checked) that if the Double_list_struct class hadn't included an operator< function I would have had to provide one.

Cheers!